# IONIC3 - ionic cordova build android fail because build.gradle is wrong

Tags: cordova, gradle, build.gradle, ionic3

When I execute `ionic cordova build android` the command show this output

> - Where:
>     Build file 'C:\Users\otta\mobile\bahiadeportes-mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 326
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\otta\mobile\bahiadeportes-mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle'.
>
> startup failed:
>         build file 'C:\Users\otta\mobile\bahiadeportes-mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle': 326: unexpected token: ) @ line 326, column 2.
>            })
>             ^
>         1 error

before compile the build.gradle is like this

```
.
.
.
for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

but build command adds the following to the end of the file

> )
>   }

and the file generate is

```
.
.
.
for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
})
}
```

these autogenerated lines produce the error.

Comment: Yes, Cordova/Ionic tend to mess up generated files. I would suggest to either upload all your gradle-related files so we can check them out, or do that on your own.

Comment: [files grandle](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b1ty6su5vqbclgj/AAA_XU1lroZ9vZt7MF4kUuSxa?dl=0)